# Given something like a CDF, are two variables independent?

Tags: probability, independence

I'm given that $P(X>a, Y>b) = g(a,b)$ for a given function $g$.  Note that this is not quite the CDF, because it's $X>a, Y>b$.  How can I use $g$ to tell if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
P(X \leq a, Y \leq b) &= 1-P(X>a \text{ or } Y> b) \\
&= 1- (P(X>a)+P(Y>b)-P(X>a,Y>b))\\
&=1-P(X>a)-P(Y>b)+g(a,b)\\
\end{align*}
Now $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $P(X \leq a,Y \leq b)=P(X \leq a)P(Y \leq b)$ for all $a,b$. Note that
\begin{align*}
P(X \leq a)P(Y \leq b)&=(1-P(X>a))(1-P(Y>b))\\
&=1-P(X>a)-P(Y>b)+P(X>a)P(Y>b).
\end{align*}
So $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $g(a,b)=P(X>a)P(Y>b)$.